# How to remove/edit a malformedline from sources.list?

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, virtualbox, update-manager

guys.
i wanted to install virtualbox on my Ubuntu 18.04 lts,but when i run **sudo apt update**,i get this :
**E: Malformed entry 53 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list (Component)
E: The list of sources could not be read.**

Here is that list:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 18.04 LTS _Bionic Beaver_ - Release amd64 (20180426)]/ bionic main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://lt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
# deb-src http://lt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://lt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://lt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://lt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
# deb-src http://lt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
deb http://lt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
# deb-src http://lt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://lt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
# deb-src http://lt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
deb http://lt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://lt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://lt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://lt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu multiverse
deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian bionic contrib
# deb-src http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian bionic contrib
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
```

Sorry,im a newbie in Ubuntu,but as i see the problem is with this one
`**deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu multiverse**` (??)

Where can be a problem?
thank u !

Answer (score 5):

The incorrect line is this one:

`deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu multiverse`

The ubuntu release name is missing.

The correct line:

`deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic multiverse`

already exists 2 lines above the incorrect one and it contains the release name: `bionic`.

You should delete or comment out with a `#` the incorrect line, save the `sources.list` file and run:

`sudo apt update`

right after you save it.

**Editing steps:**

1. Open a terminal and type `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`.
2. Give your user password to proceed.
3. Find line 53 (`deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu multiverse`).
4. Add `#` and a space in the beginning of that line.
5. The line should look like this now: `# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu multiverse`.
6. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd> and answer the question to save the modified file with <kbd>Y</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
7. Now the file should be saved and the editor should be closed. Run `sudo apt update` for the system to be informed about the changes you made and you should be OK.

Comment: Can u please write  for me steb by step ,what i must do,cuz i only yesterday opened ubuntu universe for myself xD
I open the terminal ,what i need to do next to edit that row?
im stupid af

Comment: I suggest removing that line. Why keep it?

Comment: I have added the steps you need in my answer.

Comment: @Pilot6, I proposed the commenting out  as an easier solution. Removing the line entirely is better of cource.

Comment: Its some kinda magic !Thank u a lot!

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept this answer by clicking on the tick sign on the top left of the answer if everything is OK now, so that your issue is marked as solved.  :)